# Let bindings and dynamic scope in SML

Tags: functional-programming, scope, closures, sml

I'm taking the Programming Languages course on Coursera and I'm having trouble understanding the following examples regarding static and dynamic scopes.

Consider the code sample and the quiz associated with it

```
fun f g = let val x = 9 in g() end
val x = 7
fun h() = x+1
val y = f h
```

> What value does y have under lexical scope (like in ML) and under
> dynamic scope (unlike in ML)?

The answer to the question is "*8 under lexical scope and 10 under dynamic scope*" and the reason given is "*Under dynamic scope, the body of function h would end up "seeing" the local binding of x to 9 and if we removed this local binding (since it appears to have no purpose), then dynamic scope would lead to an undefined variable.*"

Consider the following code snippet and the explanation given as to why dynamic scope wouldn't work for this case.

```
fun f y =
 let val q = y+1 
 in fn z => q + y + z
 end
val g = f 4
val y = 5
val z = g 6
```

*Under dynamic scope, now the call to g 6 will make no sense: we will try to look up q, but there is no q in the environment at the call-site.*

In the first example, the local val binding in the let expression "val x = 9" was considered while in the second example "val q = y+1" is not considered. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like dynamic scope as it usually works.

Comment: @molbdnilo , are you referring to the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example `val x = 9` is in scope when `g()` is called, so `g` can see it under dynamic scoping rules.

In the second example, `val q = y+1` is only in scope inside `f`. It is not in scope when `g` is called on the line `val z = g 6`.

Comment: In the first example, 'if we removed the local binding of x to 9, then dynamic scope would lead to an undefined variable'. Since there is another global binding of x to 7, wouldn't that be used instead of throwing undefined variable exception?

Comment: @srib You're right, if you removed the local x, it should use the global x, not cause an undefined variable error. That seems to be a mistake in the text.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So can I assume that in dynamic scoping, if a higher order function that returns other function has local variables (assume that the program doesn't have global variable with the same name as the local variable), the program will fail to compile?

Comment: @srib Usually dynamic scope is checked at runtime, not compile time, so the program wouldn't fail to compile, but it would fail with an exception at runtime. In a language that's dynamically scoped but statically typed, yes, a program would not compile if you return `fn x => x+y` from a function and then call it somewhere where `y` is not defined (note, it does not have to be global - you can have a local variable at the call site) and it does not make a difference whether the function that returns `fn x => x+y` defines a variable named `y` or not.

Comment: In other words: There are no lexical closures in dynamically scoped languages.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!